# How make LVM Snapshots to back in time, in case of bad or non working instalation

Tags: partitioning, lvm, snapshot

I have LVM in my ubuntu installation and i want to know how I can make a snapshot of the whole system, if possible,
for example if I install a experimental software and i don't like it, go back in time.... it is possible??
or make a snapshot and use it to install the experimental software and when I'm done I return to my normal ubuntu, is it possible?

I already read various articles about this but I not understand:

Here:
http://www.tecmint.com/take-snapshot...estore-in-lvm/
in step 1, when i issue the command "sudo vgs" shows me that i have only one named ubuntu-vg and no free space

here:
http://tldp.org/HOWTO/LVM-HOWTO/snapshots_backup.html
is the same, it say "we now want to use the extra space in the 'ops' volume group" but where is my extra space???

Maybe I have to create a new partition?

Comment: Not an answer, but BTRFS is way better for this than LVM because it stores only differences between snapshots and current state, not the whole. See BTRFS subvolumes and snapshots.